# How to create 2 SNS Topics on 2 folders in single S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns

I have an S3 bucket with 2 folders (ABC & DEF). files are uploaded into these 2 folders. Can we create a cloudformation template which creates 2 SNS Topics on these 2 folders respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

The aws s3 bucket property LifeCycleConfig.Rule is an array.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig.html

All you need to do is specify two life cycle notification rules with the two different prefixes:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig-rule.html#cfn-s3-bucket-lifecycleconfig-rule-prefix

The catch is that the two prefixes cannot overlap.

Also, just so you know, there's no concept of "folder" in s3. AWS console achieves the illusion of folder by calling list s3 object api with delimeter of "/"

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/v2-RESTBucketGET.html